# Powershell wildcard exclude end of a file name

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have a folder with files in the following format produced by a 3rd party program.

Database_Server1_tempdb_29_10_2012_00_22_00.pdf
Database_Server1_tempdb_28_10_2012_00_21_14.pdf
Database_Server1_tempdb_27_10_2012_00_10_00.pdf
etc
etc

I want to copy one of these files from 7 days ago using only the dateformat in the file dd_mm_yyyy and ignoring the timestamp nn_nn_nn.pdf

So using a previous script to test with if I cheat and make the file this format 
Database_Server1_tempdb_22_10_2012.pdf

The following code works fine.

$pastdays = -7

$pastdate = [datetime]::Now.AddDays($pastdays)

$filename -match "Database_Server1_tempdb_" + $pastdate.Day + "*" + $pastdate.Month + "*" + $pastdate.Year+ ".pdf"

Copy-Item -Path "V:\Capacity Manager Size reports\$($filename)" "\Server2\report_Archive"

Anyone help make it work so I dont need to cheat and it just ignores whatever is after the dd_mm_yy to make its match.

Thanks

Mo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. You are trying to guess the name, instead just get all files from folder and pick the one that match, like this:

```
$pastdays = -7
$pastdate = [datetime]::Now.AddDays($pastdays)
$files = Get-ChildItem "V:\Capacity Manager Size reports\"
$filename = ($files | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "Database_Server1_tempdb_" + $pastdate.Day  + "_" + $pastdate.Month + "_" + $pastdate.Year+ "*.pdf"})
Copy-Item -Path $filename.FullName "\Server2\report_Archive"
```